# How to Minify Google Fonts in according to pass CSS Minification Test?

Tags: css, .htaccess, optimization, fonts, google-fonts

I've a website (build in core PHP) with 3 different fonts imported from Google fonts. When I tried to check website speed on GTMatrix it is showing me an error like **"Some of your website's CSS files are not minified!"**

In according to pass CSS Minification Test on PingDom or GTMatrix it is mandatory to fix all the minification issue to get high rank. I tried with many solution like GZip compression and few tweaks in `.htaccess` file. But Google Fonts still have Minification issue.

If there any other way to fix this issue?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is likely because your fonts are not loaded ***Locally***.

First all, realise that following sites like GTMetrix religously does not mean your website is passing standards. Use Googles tools, like Page Speed Insights.

If you wanted to be able to minify your fonts, then you need to download the actual fonts to your web server and load them locally from there. It is not possible to use `.htaccess` to minify external files.

Also, don't punish yourself for not achieving 100%... that is just not a reality unless you have a really basic website.

**Tools for you to make use of:**

- [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
- [Google Mobile Friendly Test](https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly)
- [Hubspot - Website Grader](https://website.grader.com/)
- [iwebchk Web Analysis](https://iwebchk.com/) (This can only be used once a week, unless you pay)
- [Varvy SEO Tool](https://varvy.com/)

These tools should help you, especially the Google tools.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Actually I was thinking the same, it's not possible to Minify direct Google Fonts without importing it locally from server. Let see if someone may help me out here. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem @AbhishekKumbhani :)